# MySQL calculate percentage across rows by dates in a range

Tags: mysql, calculation

I am using MySQL 5.6, and I have a table containing a lot of records such as this...

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id | date       | price |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | 2000-01-01 |  1.56 |
|  1 | 2000-01-05 |  1.90 |
|  1 | 2000-02-02 |  1.44 |
|  2 | 2000-01-01 | 10.99 |
|  2 | 2000-01-07 |  9.88 |
|  2 | 2000-02-01 |  9.64 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

For each ID, I would like to return the following...

1. ID
2. Minimum date >= 1 month ago
3. Maximum date <= todays date
4. Percentage difference in the price, based on the prices on the 2 dates returned
5. perhaps even show the price on those dates

e.g. if the table data was (with today being 2000-02-01)...

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id | date       | price |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | 2000-01-01 |  1.00 |
|  1 | 2000-02-01 |  1.10 |
|  2 | 2000-01-04 |  1.00 |
|  2 | 2000-02-01 |  2.00 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

Then I would expect to see...

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id | min        | max        | percentage |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2000-01-01 | 2000-02-01 |        10% |
|  2 | 2000-01-04 | 2000-02-01 |       100% |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

So my questions are, How do I do this?, and more importantly, what are the logical steps in working this out?

Comment: Please format that sample data as code to be more readable

Comment: Also, Please add your SQL that you attempted.

Comment: @Patriot, it all looked good when I view it before submitting, but once submitted it looked terrible. I have now changed it.

Comment: @Wannabe-Coder SO removes line breaks unless you enclose the text in a code block.

Comment: @Raky, sorry I binned it all in frustration :-(
The best I managed was to get the min/max date, but I was unable to get any further.

Comment: Logical steps would be: 1) learn SQL   2) upgrade MySQL 5.6 to a more recent version   3) Typ in the SQL code you learned in step 1.

Comment: @Luuk, I am trying to learn on the fly, so I haven't just asked because I can't be bothered. Admittedly, I should have kept, and then included the SQL that I have tried. My bad :-(
With regards to using a newer version of MySQL, that is out of my control.

Comment: @Patriot, thanks for the heads up regarding the line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with this, it leaves plenty of room for improvement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS price;
CREATE TABLE price (id int ,`date` date,price decimal(8,2));
INSERT INTO price VALUES
('1','2000-01-01','1.56'),
('1','2000-01-05','1.90'),
('1','2000-02-02','1.44'),
('2','2000-01-01','10.99'),
('2','2000-01-07','9.88'),
('2','2000-02-01','9.64');


select id,`min`,`max`,`price1`,`price2`,
    round((price2-price1)/price1*100,2) as `percentage`
from (
   select id,`min`,`max`,
       (select price from price p1 where p1.id=x.id and p1.`date`=x.`min`) as price1,
       (select price from price p1 where p1.id=x.id and p1.`date`=x.`max`) as price2
   from (
      select 
         id,
         min(`date`) as `min`,
         max(`date`) as `max`
      from price
      where `date` between '2000-01-01' and '2000-02-01'
      -- where `date` between date_add(current_date(), INTERVAL -1 month) and current_date()
      group by id) x
   ) x2;
```

NOTE: The commented `WHERE` clause is to filter the last month before the current date. The used WHERE clause is just to make it work with the sample data.

NOTE2: I named the table `price` because no name was given in the question. I you did need a solution which would fit better in your current situation you should have provided the `create table...` (DDL) for the table you use, together with some sample data.

NOTE3: You should not use [Reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) as column names, like `date`,`min` and `max` in this code...

Comment: thank you for your response, that is exactly what I needed. I will now go away and discect your answer to understand how it works.
I will also take on board all the comments and will try to ask better questions in the future :-(
I will also try to learn more about SQL, but TBH, like a lot of things in coding, learning something is not a 5 minute task, and forums like this one are usually a lot quicker to get an answer.

Comment: again for my edification, when you say "room for improvement", are you talking performance, or something else?

Comment: The "room for improvement" is needed when you have more data than 6 records, and no indexes.

Comment: While I agree that it's good practice to avoid using keywords as table/column identifiers, none of the words mentioned are reserved